# Compare char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char, compare

If I had an array of characters for example:

```
A = [w, o, r, n, g, , w, o, r, d]
```

And another array for example:

```
B = [c, o, r, r, e, c, t, , w, o, r, d, .]
```

I need to compare the words in array A (which are separated by a blank space) to array B and if any of the words in the first array exist in the second array, then that word should be printed. So for example, since "word" exists in the first array and in the second array, then "word" should be printed out.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Is it mandatory you use C and arrays? Could you use C++ and standard library containers instead? If so, you could store the words in a vector (or something similar), and the means for searching and manipulating the container's contents are much easier. This is a more modern way of doing things as opposed to plain C and built-in arrays.

Comment: is that homework, by any chance? what did you try? where did you get stuck? Do you know the basic syntax of the C programming language?

Comment: @Dabbler, Yes. Unfortunately, I have to use C. I have a java programming mindset and for some reason, C is really confusing to me.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I don't know the C syntax, and Google is giving me all the answers for C# and C++. I know that I need to use a foor-loop, iterate through each array, use a tokenizer in a while-loop to separate words by space and periods and say if A[i] == B[j] then print out the word. I'm a java programmer and almost know nothing about C.

Comment: @MarlonBrando, if you are a Java programmer, C syntax should not be too strange to you. This kind of exercise is exactly the right way to learn C then.

Comment: Are you really Marlon Brando? I *love* your movies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how I would do it:

You will need a function that, given an array of `char`, splits it in an array of words (and put them in C strings, NUL terminated please :-) ). I would put the length of this array and the array in a struct

```
struct WordCollection
{
    size_t NumWords;
    char **Words;
}
```

Now... How to do this function?

Let's say we "cheat" a little and decide that our arrays `A` and `B` are NUL terminated (or if they are `.` terminated like B, then you replace the `.` with a NUL). Now, this being C, you should first count the number of spaces in the string, allocate an array of `char*` (`WordCollection::Words`) big enough to contain `n + 1` `char*` (and put this `n + 1` in `WordCollection::NumWords`) and using [strtok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) "tokenize" the string and put the words in the array you created.

Then you should (could) split the A and B array in words using this function. You'll obtain two `WordCollection`, A1 and B1.

To make it quicker, I would [qsort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zes7xw0h.aspx) B1.

Then for each word in A1 you [bsearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0k41tbs.aspx) it in B1 (it isn't a bad word... It means Binary Search, and it's a quick method of searching something in an ordered array)

Done :-)

I'll add that, if this is the first time you use `bsearch` and `qsort`, it's better you look at the samples you can find around. Their syntax can be "tricky".

Now... I know you won't look at the code :-) so I'll put it here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct WordCollection
{
    size_t NumWords;
    char **Words;
};

void splitWord(char *str, struct WordCollection *wc)
{
    char *c;
    char **currentWord;

    c = str;

    wc->NumWords = 1;

    while (*c != '.')
    {
        if (*c == ' ')
        {
            wc->NumWords++;
        }

        c++;
    }

    *c = '\0';

    wc->Words = (char**)malloc(wc->NumWords * sizeof(char*));

    c = strtok(str, " ");

    currentWord = wc->Words;

    while (c)
    {
        *currentWord = c;
        currentWord++;

        c = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int myComp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp(*(const char**)p1, *(const char**)p2);
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = { 'w', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '.' };
    char b[] = { 'c', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '.' };

    struct WordCollection a1, b1;
    struct WordCollection *pSmaller, *pBigger;

    size_t i;

    splitWord(a, &a1);
    splitWord(b, &b1);

    if (a1.NumWords <= b1.NumWords)
    {
        pSmaller = &a1;
        pBigger = &b1;
    }
    else
    {
        pSmaller = &b1;
        pBigger = &a1;
    }

    qsort(pBigger->Words, pBigger->NumWords, sizeof(char*), myComp);

    for (i = 0; i < pSmaller->NumWords; i++)
    {
        void *res = bsearch(&pSmaller->Words[i], pBigger->Words, pBigger->NumWords, sizeof(char*), myComp);
        if (res)
        {
            printf("Found: %s", pSmaller->Words[i]);
        }
    }

    free(a1.Words);
    free(b1.Words);

    return 0;
}
```

And on [ideone](http://ideone.com/zmALgu)

Comment: @ChrisLutz Were you telling me I should use `size_t` for the number of words? Technically I don't "need" to do it. I could simply say that the program "supports" a maximum number of 10 words :-)

Comment: @Chris Lutz I see you say `s/int/size_t/g` a lot. I don't know what it means. Can you explain?

Comment: @Marlon I think it was an oblique reference to the fact that I was using a `int` for `NumWords`. In C when you "count" elements of memory it's normally better to use `size_t`. And I think he is using the format of some sed or other similar tool to "replace" the `int` in `size_t`. Unfortunately I'm an obtuse Windows user :-)

Comment: @xanatos, Thanks for answering. I was thinking of doing it this way: I need to use a foor-loop, iterate through each array, use a tokenizer in a while-loop to separate words by space and periods and say if A[i] == B[j] then print out the word. What do you think?

Comment: @MarlonBrando That if you do it this way you have a complexity O(M*N), if you do it as I've said you only have a complexity O(M*logN) :-) And if you want to be super, you decide which of A and B is M and N by choosing the biggest as N and the smallest as M (the array that is sorted is N)

Comment: @xanatos can you elaborate a little more on "allocate an array of char* (WordCollection::Words) big enough to contain n + 1 char* (and put this n + 1 in WordCollection::NumWords)"?

Comment: @MarlonBrando If you have n + 1 words, and `struct WordCollection wc;`  and `wc.NumWords = n + 1` and `wc.Words = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * wc.NumWords);`

Comment: @xanatos Why do I need to count the number of spaces?

Comment: @MarlonBrando: because you create an an array whose size is the number of words. Counting the spaces is a way to find it out

Comment: @MarlonBrando And I'll add that doing the reverse (tokenizing and then creating the array) is much more difficult because it requires the use of realloc or the use of an intermediate linked list.

Comment: @MarlonBrando - xanatos got it right. It's Perl regular expression syntax for "replace all occurrences of `int` with `size_t`". I use it because I'm lazy and posting from my phone.

Comment: @xanatos will you marry me? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to somehow separate the words, and then iterate through the combinations.  There are a hundred ways to do this -- it simply requires programming.

Comment: I don't know the C syntax, and Google is giving me all the answers for C# and C++. I know that I need to use a foor-loop, iterate through each array, use a tokenizer in a while-loop to separate words by space and periods and say if A[i] == B[j] then print out the word. I'm a java programmer and almost know nothing about C. So I'd appreciate your help, if you're trying to help and not bashing your programming skills in my face. Thanks.

Comment: [Get yourself a copy of K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) so that you can stop saying "I don't know the C syntax".

Comment: Work out how you'd do it in Java if you worked purely with char arrays and didn't use String or any of the java.util stuff.  That will transliterate into C fairly easily.  (I see no point in using a tokenizer, regardless.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like that:

1. Insert all words from set A into set C with suffix 'A'. You will get => 
   `worngA`
   `wordA`
2. Insert all words from set B into set C with suffix 'B'. You will get => 
   `correctB`
   `wordB`
3. Run sorting algo on set C such as qsort. You will get => 
   `correctB`
   `wordA`
   `wordB`
   `worngA`
4. Loop in set C until it's size-1. Compare `word[i]` with `word[i+1]` - if they match except the last letter - you found duplicate and you can print it out.

I don't know about this algorithm complexity, but it clearly should be faster than just brute-force scan of all words combinations :-)